# Admob Ads don't load after updating to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, google-play-services

I recently updated the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' dependendcies to 17.1.2 and my admob Ads won't load anymore. I used version 11 for a very long time and never had any issues but after updating they won't show anymore.

After I looked at the documentaion I realized that you have to initialize the APP-ID in the Launch activity and in the Manifest, so I adjusted my code but the Ads still don't show so I tried Admobs test Ad ids and they load fine.

So the problem can't be in the implemntation of admob right?

Here my build.gradle

```
     buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
}
}
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

   repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }


  android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'XX'
        keyPassword 'XX'
        storeFile file('XX')
        storePassword 'XX'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XX"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode XX
    versionName "XX"


    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}

dexOptions {

    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}

 }


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/customtabs
implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'customtabs', version: '28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'

  }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here a snippet of the Manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    >

    <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value=

            "@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".Splashscreen"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
         />

    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="XXX" />
    <!-- Sa+mple AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/google_app_id"
        />
</application>
```

My Strings.xml

```
<string name="ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-XXX/XX</string>
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-XXX~XX</string>
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-XXX/XX</string>
<string name="reward_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-XXX/XX</string>
```

Snippet of MAinactivity.class

```
  public AdView mAdView;
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.google_app_id));

            mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
 }
```

So looking at the code I really can't see a reason the ads won't load. Is there anything else you have to consider when upgrading dependencies in regard to admob ads?

Comment: I have the same problem with com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0. Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue - test ads work, but my own don't. I read somewhere that they won't load everytime you open your app, and that it takes few hours for them to show up after you add them to your app. Just go on Google AdMob console, and see impressions number - if it's not zero - they showed up on someone's phone.

Did you update your app version on Google Play? If you haven't, do it. That way you can test Google AdMob console solution, or let me know the name of the app, so I can check if I see ads myself.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks and  no I didn't updated it yet. I have one version online in the store running with a older Google ads version  and it works fine. And I don't want to upload the updated before I got that sorted. Do have an email address, so I can send you the apk? Would be super nice

Comment: Yup, its natasa2604@yahoo.com.